# perl inplace replace creates empty file

Tags: perl, replace

I currently have a sed command to make an inplace replace of all backslashes in a file - this works fine but is quite slow. I read that perl would be faster so want to try this out but have hit a problem.

The Perl command I am using is:

```
perl -p -i -e 's/\\//g' mytestfile.csv
```

omitting the -i flag echos the correct output to screen but with the -i flag included it overwrites mytestfile.csv with zero content, which is not what I expected - obviously the command is first truncating mytestfile.csv

How do I get the perl inplace replace to work?

Comment: What platform are you on? Only thing I can think of is `-i` doesn't work well on Windows, because of how it handles open files. Trying `-i.bak` instead might do the trick

Comment: Running on RHEL 5   - I just tried your suggestion of -i.bak and it works. Not entirely solved the issue but it works and that's good enough at the moment. Thanks.

Comment: As written, your code works on my CentOs box. So I don't know what's going wrong with it. Are you sure that's exactly as written, and you're not redirecting or anything?

Comment: Exactly as written, no output redirect.

Comment: My next best would be: try running `strace -fTt perl -p -i -e 's/\\//g' mytestfile.csv` and have a look at what it's doing. But it really _should_ be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments:

- I can't reproduce your problem. Your code seems to work fine on my box.
- Try `-i.bak` which will backup your old file (to `filename.bak`) before processing.
- Windows handles inplace editing differently, because of how file locking works. That doesn't seem to apply here.